# Laravel Bootstrap Modal Submit button not working

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.5

I'm crazy trying to make a modal window return the control to my view. The button  type is submit but it doesn't launch the route. I've seen some tutorials and there, all I have to do for create is to define action as the route and have a submit button. I've seen that, no need of ajax, or I'm not aware when they wrote the code... I went to w3c and there at the "try it yourself" I agregated the submit button, and effectively the window is not closed. So I'm totally stuck, some help would be appreciated.

Part of my view

```
    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h5">Horarios</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create-horario">+</button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="create-horario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" >
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Nuevo horario</h5>                      
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>


                  </div>

                  <form action="{{ route('horarioperiodicos.store')}}" method="post">
         <!--           {{ method_field('patch')}} -->
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="modal-body">


                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="diaSemana" class="col-form-label">Día de la semana</label>
                        <select name="diaSemana" class="form-control">
                          <option value="1"  selected> Lunes</option>
                          <option value="2"  > Martes</option>
                          <option value="3"  > Miércoles</option>
                          <option value="4"  > Jueves</option>
                          <option value="5"  > Viernes</option>
                          <option value="6"  > Sábado</option>
                          <option value="7"  > Domingo</option>
                          </select> 
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="width:50%;float:left;display:inline-block;">
                          <label for="HoraInicio" class="col-form-label">Hora de inicio</label>
                          <input type="time" id="HoraInicio" name="HoraInicio" min="9:00" max="18:00" value="09:00" >
                        </div>
                        <div align="right">
                          <label for="HoraFin" class="col-form-label">Hora de fin</label>
                          <input type="time" id="HoraFin" name="HoraFin" min="9:00" max="18:00" value="10:00">
                        </div>
                      </div>


                    </div>
                   </form>

                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Guardar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Día</th>
          <th>Hora de inicio</th>
          <th>Hora de fin</th>        
          <th>Cambios</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        @foreach($horarioPeriodicos as $horario)
          <tr>
            <td>  

              @switch( $horario->intDia )
                  @case( 1 )
                      Lunes
                    @break
                  @case( 2 )
                      Martes
                  @case( 3 )
                      Miércoles
                    @break
                  @case( 4 )
                      Jueves
                  @case( 5 )
                      Viernes
                  @case( 6 )
                      Sábado
                  @default
                      Domingo
                    @break
              @endswitch

            </td>
            <td> {{ $horario->timHoraInicio }} </td>
            <td> {{ $horario->timHoraFin }} </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">-</button> / 
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Editar</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach


      </tbody>
    </table>




    </main>
```

HorarioPeriodicosController (don't get to it and is in my rotes list)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    dd(1);
}
```

[My routes list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEK7F.png)

I tryed modifying this

```
                  <form action="{{ route('horarioperiodicos.store')}}" method="post">
                    {{ method_field('patch')}}
```

for this

```
                  <form action="{{ route('horarioperiodicos.store')}}" >
```

etc, etc.

Something rare is that even when I do changes there, It doesn't launch errors.

Thanks a lot

Comment: First of all, you can use Carbon to get the day of week, instead this switchs cases example: ` Carbon::now()->dayName `. You're using patch method field to store a value, and this isn't right, this method should be use in updates, try use just the csrf_field. If the error persist try do a jsfiddle of the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place your `<button>` *inside* of the `<form>` element.

Otherwise the form will not be triggered to submit.

*Alternatively* you can place the button outside of the form, but you need to include the `form=` attribute that corresponds with the form's `id=` attribute in the button element:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="{{ route('store.create') }}">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="myform" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new with it, but should supposed it. As easy as that.